# Не видит таблицу в database PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js

Таблица в базе данных есть. Но при запросе выдает query error: relation "info" does not exist.
Что я делаю не таК?

```
var pg = require("pg");

function ConnectToDb() {
var pool = new pg.Pool({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "5432",
    user: "postgres",
    password: "111111",
    database: "HRS"
});

pool.connect(function (err,client,done) {
    if(err)console.log("connect "  + err.toString());

    else
    client.query('Select* From Info',function (err,result) {

        if(err) console.log("query "+err.toString());
        else console.log(result);
        done();
    });


});
pool.end();
}

exports.res = ConnectToDb;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вывод `\dt` покажи

Comment: Просто, это что?

Comment: в консоли psql набери эти 3 символа и покажи вывод

Comment: Добавил,вот что пишет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот таким запросом,тогда вопрос, почему добовлять нужно public к имени таблици?

```
  pool.connect(function (err,client,done) {
    if(err)console.log("connect "  + err.toString())
   else
    client.query('SELECT *' +
        'FROM public."Info";',function (err,result) {

        if(err) console.log("query "+err.toString());
        else console.log(result);
        done();
    });
```

Comment: добавление имени схемы public имеет значение при изменённом search_path. Но в вашем случае не влияет. А влияет `"Info"`. `relation "info" does not exist` - внимание на регистр. Имена объектов без кавычек парсер postgresql приводит к нижнему регистру, имена в кавычках - не трогает. Если у вас таблица создана именно `Info` - то к ней возможно обращаться именно через `"Info"`